# Will a 2.5" SSD fit in my Toshiba Portege R830?

Tags: laptop, ssd, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Portege R830 - X3310.

Unfortunately my HDD gave up and I am thinking of switching to a SSD. Does any one have any idea if a Corsair Force GS will fit? The SSD is a 2.5" disk.

I tried searching but was not able to find any information on the dimensions of the HDD used in the laptop.

The Model No. for the Corsair SSD is CSSD-F240GBGS-BK.

The confusion is about some claims on a proprietary connector. I currently have a standard spinning 500GB HDD.

Comment: If you can provide the model of the hard drive, it will be easier to ascertain for certain, but yes - it should fit.  The Corsair drive is 9.5mm high, which is a standard height for a hard drive (although there are a few which are smaller) - for example the Samsung 840 series are 7.5mm high.

Comment: For shorter drives, the retail kits (as opposed to OEM) usually come with risers that make them the standard size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two standard sizes for 2.5 inch hard drives these days. Smaller/Thinner notebooks like ultrabooks systems use 7mm drives and the 'standard' for quite a while has been 9 inch. You should be able to fit a 7 mm drive in a 'larger' bay with no problem but not vice versa.

Looking up the drive model indicates that crucial's [upgrade advisor](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=45A67D30A5CA7304) suggests that the m4 works, and thats a 9.5mm drive and the drive on the [Toshiba service video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWlHFs31NWI) looks standard as well. The [cosair force is *also* 9.5mm](http://www.custompcreview.com/reviews/corsair-force-series-gs-240gb-ssd-review/16025/2/), so there should be no issues here

Answer (score 0):

Any 2.5" ssd or hdd should work in your portege.